# General approach for isolating a WLAN with iptables?

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to use a 2-port plus WiFi adapter NAS as a home router, and I'd like to know roughly how big an undertaking the following would be using iptables:

- forward masqueraded client traffic from the LAN and WLAN subnets to WAN
- segregate WLAN from LAN completely except for DNS traffic to 192.168.1.1:53
- allow OpenVPN clients to see both the LAN and the WAN/Internet

The interfaces are as follows:

```
eth0: xx.xx.xx.xx/23 - WAN
eth1: 192.168.1.1/24 - LAN
lbr0: 192.168.2.1/24 - WLAN
tun0: 192.168.3.1/24 - OpenVPN clients
```

Using simple forwarding, I've at least gotten NATing from both the LAN and WLAN working but offer no isolation:

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
# iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o lbr0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A FORWARD -i lbr0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

I get the feeling this should be pretty straightforward, but I'm a complete novice with iptables. Is there a good tutorial for this anywhere, or can somebody give me any direct advice on this problem? I've already punched a hole into `eth0`'s blanket deny filter for the OpenVPN server, and I don't think I have any port forwarding concerns except the DNS on the WLAN and OpenVPN segments.

Is this as simple as adding some `DROP` rules and some sort of `ACCEPT` overrides for the DNS, or am I missing something substantial?

Answer (score 1):

You are not. But I think it would be simpler and more ideological to change the FORWARD policy to DROP, and then adding just the rules you need in order the packet forwarding works only when needed. This will exclude any possible mistakes.

You could also use another approach, which is more complex, but also more flexible. You could create separate routing tables for your LAN, WLAN and VPN, containing only the routes needed (excluding the on-interface routes you don't need - for example excluding the LAN on-interface route from WAN FIB).